# What to do with broken iPhone 3G?

Tags: iphone, screen

A friend order an iPhone 4 to replace his iPhone 3G which has a cracked screen. He offered it to me.

I have AT&T on a family plan with no text or data. What should I do with the phone?

I'm open to suggestions, but I'm considering...

- fixing the screen and then selling it. I'd put that money towards purchasing the iPhone 4 with a data plan.
- fixing the screen and keeping it.
- selling without fixing the screen.

I guess I could keep it without fixing the screen too, but...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can buy very cheap screen replacements on ebay (about AU$30). I have fitted one of these myself, it is not too hard.

Comment: I probably will do this, but not from eBay. I prefer iFixit (or anything) over eBay.

Answer (score 1):

I sold mine *without* fixing it and got a nice price on ebay.

Comment: A 3G? I'm curious how much. The 3G *S* is $99 *new*.

Comment: somewhat over $100. Don't ask me to explain it, I can't.

Comment: Nice price. Don't bother explaining. ;)

Comment: The price probably fell since iPhone 4 came out.

Comment: @Moshe the phone fell, the price fell ...

Comment: @bmargulies - :-)

Answer (score 0):

use it as a [External HardDrive](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/6-ways-to-turn-your-iphone-into-an-external-hard-disk/).